# Colouring of 3DPlot

Tags: graphics3d, color

I have a `ParametricPlot3D` in which I would like to change colouring to meet the rest of my work. There seems to be some orange colour as the basic one which is toned into black and white to create the 3D effect. I would like to change the orange colour to red (#FF0000), is it possible?

A sample code is:

```
r[t_, ϕ0_] = { R[t] Cos[ϕ0], R[t] Sin[ϕ0], t}
ParametricPlot3D[r[t, ϕ0], {ϕ0, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

I tried `PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1], Specularity[Black, 5]]` but it did not seem right.

I do **not** want to colour according to a coordinate, I want the colouring according to light.

I have Mathematica 10.4.

Comment: Try `Lighting -> "Neutral"`

Comment: Thank you very much, consider making a short answer I could mark as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to locate the function `R[t]` so I made one up.

I also changed the `BoxRatios` to make it a bit easier to see.

```
R[t_] := 4 + Cos[\[Pi] t]
r[t_, ϕ0_] = {R[t] Cos[ϕ0], R[t] Sin[ϕ0], t}

ParametricPlot3D[r[t, ϕ0], {ϕ0, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &},
 Axes -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot3D[r[t, ϕ0], {ϕ0, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &},
 Axes -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ImageSize -> 300,
 ColorFunction -> (Red &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]